# SDK versions before v10 will stop receiving updates, including compatibility and bug fixes

Tags: android, ios, mapbox

I received an email from Mapbox stating that for both the Android and iOS SDKs, versions before v10 will stop receiving updates, including compatibility and bug fixes

Does this mean the SDK will fully stop working and we **have** to update the SDKs before April 4, 2023?

Or will it just be deprecated and we can and should update at the earliest chance, even if that is after the April 4th cut off date?

I believe that it will just be deprecated and won't actually stop working after April 4th but would appreciate any confirmation of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or will it just be deprecated and we can and should update at the earliest chance, even if that is after the April 4th cut off date?

This is the correct answer